# simulation errors in implementing xilinx fifo core

Tags: verilog, xilinx, fifo

I have generated a core IP from Xilinx core generator for FIFO. I get some errors while simulating the design.

In stimulus my clock switches on every #1 and write flag is also set at #1 followed by din and again write flag unset at #1. Followed by same thing with read flag

The problems are:
1. Full flag is set earlier than the data is filled with FIFO.
2. The read won't start from first pointer, instead starts with 4th read pointer.

Any suggestions?

```
initial begin

    clk = 0;
    rst = 0;
    rst = 1;
    #1 rst = 0;
    wr_en = 0;
    rd_en = 0;

    for (i=0; i<1024; i=i+1) begin : wr_loop
        #1 wr_en = 1;
        din <= i;//$urandom_range(5,14);
        #1 wr_en = 0;
    end

    for (j=0; j<1024; j=j+1) begin : rd_loop
            #1 rd_en = 1'b1;
            #1 rd_en = 1'b0;
    end

    #900000 $finish;
end

    always #1 clk = ~clk;
```

simulation image link: (the full flag should raise after 1024 entries)

Comment: `din <= 1` guarantees that the data is fassigned **after** your wr_en is set. Why do you use the **non-blocking** assighment there? You just create races in your test bench. Can you elaborate on `2. The read won't start from first pointer, instead starts with 4th read pointer.`?

Comment: where is the code for full pointer & read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a timing issue. If this is a FIFO synchronous to the rising `clk` edge, it may not correctly latch your `wr_en` or `rd_en` pulses.

For starters, I would try to keep `wr_en` simply high for the number of `clk` cycles you want to execute writes. Also, to avoid race conditions between your `initial` and `always` blocks, make `clk` generation part of the `initial` block and make sure the `wr_en` and `rd_en` signals change on the *in*active (usually falling) edge of `clk`.